# Compiling Multiple NASM Files For OS Mac OS X

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm

I've got two NASM files for an OS of mine I'm writing in assembly, and I'm almost 100% positive they work, but I can't tell, because I don't know exactly how to compile them. I know how to use the commands `nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin` and the `cat boot.bin > image.hdd`, but now I've got two files to use, and I don't know how to link them. I've tried compiling the two of them into separate .bin files, and then use `cat boot.bin other.bin > image.hdd` but when I try to open it with VirtualBox (I use that to test my OS things) it wont let me.

Here's the code I have in my two assembly files if you need to take a look at them

```
;--------------------------------------------
; 'boot.asm'
; loaded from BIOS

 [org 0x7C00]
 [bits 16]

;--------------------------------------------

 main:
  mov ah, 0x0E  ; print function
  mov al, '.'   ; ascii char
  int 0x10   ; IO int

 resetdisk:
  mov ah, 0x00  ; reset function
  mov dl, 0x00  ; drive
  int 0x13   ; disk int
  jc resetdisk

 readdisk:
  mov bx, 0x8000  ; segment
  mov es, bx
  mov bx, 0x0000  ; offset

  mov ah, 0x02  ; read function
  mov al, 0x03  ; sectors
  mov ch, 0x00  ; cylinder
  mov cl, 0x02  ; sector
  mov dh, 0x00  ; head
  mov dl, 0x00  ; drive
  int 0x13      ; disk int
  jc readdisk
  db 0eah
  dw 00000h     ; offset
  dw 08000h     ; segment

;--------------------------------------------

 times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0x00
 db 0x55, 0xAA
```

and

```
;--------------------------------------------
 ; 'load.asm'
 ; loaded from 'boot.asm'

 [org 0x8000]
 [bits 16]

 ;--------------------------------------------

 main:
  mov ah, 0x0E  ; print function
  mov al, '.'   ; ascii char
  int 0x10   ; IO int

  jmp $    ; hang
```

SIDE NOTE: I'm on Mac OS X Mountain Lion, so I'm at my wits ends getting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a hard disk instead of a floppy image (**image.hdd**), you'd first want to change **boot.asm** like this:

```
;--------------------------------------------
; 'boot.asm'
; loaded from BIOS

 [org 0x7C00]
 [bits 16]

;--------------------------------------------

 main:
  mov ah, 0x0E  ; print function
  mov al, '.'   ; ascii char
  int 0x10   ; IO int

 resetdisk:
  mov ah, 0x00  ; reset function
  mov dl, 0x80  ; drive
  int 0x13   ; disk int
  jc resetdisk

 readdisk:
  mov bx, 0x8000  ; segment
  mov es, bx
  mov bx, 0x0000  ; offset

  mov ah, 0x02  ; read function
  mov al, 0x01  ; sectors
  mov ch, 0x00  ; cylinder
  mov cl, 0x02  ; sector
  mov dh, 0x00  ; head
  mov dl, 0x80  ; drive
  int 0x13      ; disk int
  jc readdisk
  db 0eah
  dw 00000h     ; offset
  dw 08000h     ; segment

;--------------------------------------------

 times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0x00
 db 0x55, 0xAA
```

Note that drive (**dl**) and sector count (**al**) where changed before the two int 0x13 calls.
Then you'd want to create an image that is a multiple of 512 bytes like this:

```
$ nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
$ nasm -f bin load.asm -o load.bin
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=pad504 bs=1 count=504
$ cat boot.bin load.bin pad504 > image.hdd
```

The padding is **504** bytes because **load.bin** is **8** bytes and **512 - 8 = 504**. So as you modify **load.asm**, you'd want to change the command to generate a padding of suitable size with

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=padding bs=1 count=$((512 - $(ls -l load | cut -d ' ' -f 5) % 512))
$ cat boot.bin load.bin padding > image.hdd
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked, and was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

What won't Virtualbox "let" you do?

In addition to Scottt's suggestions, I'd point out that you're reading `load.bin` to segment 0x8000 offset 0, and jumping to segment 0x8000 offset 0, but `load.asm` specifies `org 0x8000`. This is not correct. It won't bother you in this rudimentary program, but as soon as you try to print `msg`, it'll fail. Unlike an ordinary programming environment, in a boot environment there's no OS to manage your segment registers - you need to keep 'em in order yourself. `cs` is set by the far jump (or we're executing some other code altogether!)  but ds (etc.) is up to you. A sane `ss:sp` wouldn't be a bad idea, either.  You don't need this yet, but you will soon.